# Problemas de velocidad funcion O(n) con unshift()

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, bucle-for, foreach, map

Estaba haciendo un problema que dado una entrada de un arreglo `arr` regresar la suma acumulada de sus elementos en los indices posteriores... Es esto:

> Input: `arr= [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]`
>
> Ouput: `arr = [ 20, 20, 19, 16, 10, 0]`
>
> porque:
>
> `ls = [0, 1, 3, 6, 10]` *20
>
> `ls = [1, 3, 6, 10]` *20
>
> `ls = [3, 6, 10]` *19
>
> `ls = [6, 10]` *16
>
> `ls = [10]` *10
>
> `ls = []` *0

Como sabia que el tiempo de ejecución seria importante pensé en una solución O(n) iterando con `for()` mas rapido para estos casos que `forEach() map() for of` esta fue mi primera solucion

```js
function partSums(ls) {
    let resp = [0]
    let suma = 0
    let len= ls.length - 1;
    for (let i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
        suma += ls[i]
        resp.unshift(suma)
    }
    return resp
}

console.log(partSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]))
console.log(partSums([ 20, 19, 16, 10, 0 ]))
```

Pense que mas rápido que esto no encontraría una forma y que no tendria problemas... sin embargo no paso el test de velocidad..
De casualidad probando funciones hice esta y para sorpresa pase el test de velocidad...

```js
function partSums(ls) {
    let arr = [0];
    ls.reverse().forEach(v => arr.push(arr[arr.length - 1] + v));
    return arr.reverse();
}

console.log(partSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]))
console.log(partSums([11, 1, 3, 6, 10,14,32,1,3]))
console.log(partSums([11, 1, 3, 0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 6, 10,14,32,1,3]))
```

digo sorpresa porque para mi hacer `reverse()` 2 veces y utilizando `forEach()` para iterar(mas lento que el `for()`) ya seria suficiente para no pasar los test... pero era significativamente mas rapida esta funcion... otra cosa rara es que esta misma función con `map()` es casi la mitad mas lenta que `forEach()` cosa que aun no me queda clara...

Comparando estas funciones saque como conclusion que **el problema estaba en** el `unshift()`!!!

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
    let resp = [0]
    let acum = 0
    let len= ls.length - 1
    for (let i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
        acum += ls[i]
        resp.push(acum)
    }
    return resp.reverse()
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

Entonces mi pregunta es como es posible que el `unshift()` sea tanto mas costoso en tiempo que el `push()`... que el `reverse()` (que para mi tenia q hacer algo similar al `for()` cambiando indices) sea tan rapido.. y como es posible tambien que el forEach() sea casi tan rapido como el `for()` y mas que el `map()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inicialmente me gustaría señalar que podrías ahorrarte el último `reverse`, si en lugar de hacer `push` fueses agregando los resultados en `resp[i]`

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function partsSums(ls) {
    let acum = 0,
      resp = [];
    for (let i = ls.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) resp[i] = acum += ls[i];
    resp[ls.length] = 0;
    return resp;
}

console.log(partsSums([0, 1, 3, 6, 10]));
```

---

Ahora en respuesta a:

> Entonces mi pregunta es como es posible que el unshift() sea tanto mas costoso en tiempo que el push()...

Si tenemos en cuenta que `unshift(value)` significa agregar un elemento al principio del arreglo, es decir, que todos los elementos previamente agregados tienen que ser movidos de `n` a `n+1`, entonces tiene sentido que sea más lento hacer `unshift` que `push` (*agregar al final*)

Y en respuesta a:

> cómo es posible también que el forEach() sea casi tan rápido como el for() y más que el map()?

Esto depende de la implementación de cada método en cada navegador.
Por ejemplo, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map#Polyfill) si miramos su `polyfill` podríamos decir que es mas lento que un `for`, debido a que en este:

- se valida el tipo de dato
- se valida que los parámetros sean del tipo esperado
- se crea un acumulador (*arreglo de resultado*)
- y por cada elemento se ejecuta una función (*callback*)

Comment: Muchas gracias Marcos.. y optima la funcion... mas otra cosa rara es que el metodo con push es aun mas rapido que este.. sera por mi navegador y los test que veo consisten en un arreglo enorme con numeros pequeños

Comment: @IsraelGonzález, no se como estas haciendo tus pruebas. Te dejo [este simple test](http://jsben.ch/Trj8l) para que puedas ver cómo en distintos navegadores vas a obtener resultados diferentes. En mis pruebas **Firefox el 100% de las veces resulto ser más rápida mi implementación**.

Comment: Tienes toda la razon... la pagina  es la que hace los test de velocidad por mi https://www.codewars.com/kata/sums-of-parts/train/javascript volvi a comprobar y para la primera ~Completed in 1937ms para la tuya ~Completed in 3230ms.. nada debe ser algunos de los test especificos y mi navegador(estoy usando Chrome y no eh provado en otros)gracias de nuevo Marcos